# Webmachine {not_started,mochiweb}

Tags: macos, erlang, webmachine

I'm new to Erlang's Webmachine, and I'm having a bit of trouble even getting a basic "hello world" going.  Whenever I run `./start.sh`, I get a big error like this:

```
➜  webmachine git:(master) ./start.sh 
Erlang/OTP 17 [erts-6.3.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]


=PROGRESS REPORT==== 4-Mar-2015::17:27:09 ===
          supervisor: {local,sasl_safe_sup}
             started: [{pid,<0.35.0>},
                       {name,alarm_handler},
                       {mfargs,{alarm_handler,start_link,[]}},
                       {restart_type,permanent},
                       {shutdown,2000},
                       {child_type,worker}]

=PROGRESS REPORT==== 4-Mar-2015::17:27:09 ===
          supervisor: {local,sasl_safe_sup}
             started: [{pid,<0.36.0>},
                       {name,overload},
                       {mfargs,{overload,start_link,[]}},
                       {restart_type,permanent},
                       {shutdown,2000},
                       {child_type,worker}]

=PROGRESS REPORT==== 4-Mar-2015::17:27:09 ===
          supervisor: {local,sasl_sup}
             started: [{pid,<0.34.0>},
                       {name,sasl_safe_sup},
                       {mfargs,
                           {supervisor,start_link,
                               [{local,sasl_safe_sup},sasl,safe]}},
                       {restart_type,permanent},
                       {shutdown,infinity},
                       {child_type,supervisor}]

=PROGRESS REPORT==== 4-Mar-2015::17:27:09 ===
          supervisor: {local,sasl_sup}
             started: [{pid,<0.37.0>},
                       {name,release_handler},
                       {mfargs,{release_handler,start_link,[]}},
                       {restart_type,permanent},
                       {shutdown,2000},
                       {child_type,worker}]

=PROGRESS REPORT==== 4-Mar-2015::17:27:09 ===
         application: sasl
          started_at: nonode@nohost
Eshell V6.3.1  (abort with ^G)
1> 
=PROGRESS REPORT==== 4-Mar-2015::17:27:09 ===
         application: crypto
          started_at: nonode@nohost
{"init terminating in do_boot",{{badmatch,{error,{not_started,mochiweb}}},[{webmachine,start,0,[{file,"src/webmachine.erl"},{line,36}]},{init,start_it,1,[]},{init,start_em,1,[]}]}}

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
init terminating in do_boot ()
```

For what it's worth, I'm using Mac OS X, but the same error appears to happen when using Ubuntu in a Docker container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to anyone who Googles this, my issue was that I had to create a new project using the example generator, and not just run the vanilla `start.sh` that was in the cloned repo. Hope this helps people.